# How to handle an empty req.body Node.js (using body-parser)?

Tags: node.js, body-parser

The problem is that i want to handle a POST request Without any data or JSON, when i do that my app crashes.

Question : how to handle that ?

in **App.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/message', messagingRoutes);
```

in **Routes.js**

```
router.post('/' , NotController.send2Fcm );
```

in **Controller.js**

```
  {
    to: req.body.registration,
    priority: "high",
    title: req.body.title
    message: req.body.body 
    }
```

okay now , on postman , i send empty request : ( keeps loading like that)

[image: demonstration]

Comment: Your app should have an unexpected error handler.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create logic for handling an empty body:

```
if (!req.body) return res.send(*your error here*)

if (!req.body.registration || !req.body.title || !req.body.body) return res.send(*your error here*)
```